# C# complex class to SQLBulkInsert millions or rows

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I'm having an issue, apparently is very simple but I haven't found anything related.

```
public class Fruit
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string color { get; set; }
  public string shape { get; set; }
  public Image image { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

That's my "complex" class, and I want to convert this to DataTable to apply the SQLBulkCopy but when it retrieves the Image class it's not bringing the values but the data type "Image" which throws an exception.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
  PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
  DataTable table = new DataTable();
  foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
       table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);

  foreach (T item in data)
  {
       DataRow row = table.NewRow();
       foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

       table.Rows.Add(row);
   }

   return table;
}
```

Any clue on how can I retrieve the ID for the Image property to do the SQLBulkCopy?

By the way, this is the method I'm using for the insert:

```
public static void SaveToDatabase(DataTable data)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConn))
    {
        SqlTransaction transaction = null;
        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, transaction))
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Fruit";
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "name");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("color", "color");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("shape", "shape");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("image", "image");

                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(data);
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)  // Here I got the datatype Exception because I don't know how to get the Image.ID value
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

**Apparently my post it's a little bit confusing, so I'm going to add the issue here:**

How to get the **URL** and **ID** values from the **Image** *class* in the following code? Currently, it's bringing the object Image which it's unknown and throws an exception

```
sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("image", "image");
```

How can I map them? I know I can do it row by row, but I have more than 2 million rows to process on each execution. That's why I'm trying to use the bulkcopy.

**I need to add that this data comes from an API call in Json format**

Comment: Can you include the code that ties these three snippets together?  I.e., how does Fruit and ToDataTable get used/passed to your SaveToDatabase function?

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` supports only primitive types. To fill `VARBINARY(MAX)` columns (which I hope you're using rather than the deprecated `IMAGE` type, which has a misleadingly appropriate name), you need to pass a `byte[]`. But if you really need performance there, you don't want to fiddle around with potentially huge byte arrays in `DataTable`s but stream the data instead. This is more involved, however, as it involves constructing `SqlDataRecord` instances on the fly and using `SqlBytes`. There are probably libraries to simplify this, but recommending those is OT on SO.

Comment: Thanks for replying:
@RBarryYoung: `APIClient<fruit> client = new APIClient<fruit>("fruit", UserName, Password);
var retrievedData = client.GetAll();
DataTable data = new DataTable();
data = ToDataTable(retrievedData.Result);
SaveToDatabase(data);`

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for your reply: I agree with you the name is not proper, I should use Picture for the class instead of Image, I'm not looking to store and Image data type, but the Picture details of the fruit, in this case, the ID and the URL of the picture

Comment: Whoops, I completely missed your `Image` class is not, actually, an image (as in, actual bitmap data per `System.Drawing.Image`), just a sub-entity of two columns. Regardless of how you insert, you cannot store an object directly in a column (SQL Server is not an O-O database). You can do things like store JSON or XML to serialize the data into a column, use an ORM like Entity Framework (or for slightly less complicated scenarios Dapper), or just split the "object" (which is not much in this case) into two separate columns.

Comment: Code is not very legible in the comments, so If you can, just edit your question and add the code there.  (I’d do it for you, but I’m on my mobile device right now and editing is a pain on mobile)

Comment: What @JeroenMostert said.  If you use non-standard data types, then you have to have special intervening code to change it into something that SQLBulkCopy understands, which is why I wanted to see the connecting code...

Comment: And before anyone else brings this up I should probably do it myself: technically you *can* store objects in columns, by adding the types as CLR types to your database, but for primitive objects that have no methods this is definitely not worth doing in terms of effort, overhead, ease of use and maintenance, which is why ORMs exist.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't copy the Fruit class correctly, my bad as I'm working in a Virtual Machine and not allowed to copy, I'm copying manually.

Comment: I added the main question in the bottom of the post, hope that's a little bit clear, thanks all for your contributions

Answer (score 1):

After modifying the code to test this I did find a solution:

```
if (prop.GetChildProperties().Count > 1)
    row[prop.Name] = (Image)prop.GetValue(item);
else
    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
```

The solution was only to cast the GetValue to the Image class, this was applied in the ToDataTable method:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
  PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
  DataTable table = new DataTable();
  foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
       table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);

  foreach (T item in data)
  {
       DataRow row = table.NewRow();
       foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
           if (prop.GetChildProperties().Count > 1)
               row[prop.Name] = (Image)prop.GetValue(item);
           else
               row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

       table.Rows.Add(row);
   }

   return table;
}
```

**Thank you all for your time and help!**